# Connecting individual microservices exposed via graphQL to an application gateway aggregation layer

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, microservices, apollo-server, express-graphql

Taking into consideration the microservices architecture, let's say that we have two microservices which are exposing graphQL at

```
localhost:4000/graphql
localhost:4001/graphql
```

Now I need to write one application gateway layer in nodeJS , say exposed at

```
 https://hostname/api
```

via kubernetes ingress rule.

Now please help in following contexts -

---

1. How can I call services S1 and S2 mentioned above, via this application gateway

   a. If they are dependent on each other

   b. if they are independent of each other

---

2. What graphql components of S1 and S2 should be kept in application gateway ( like aggregated Schema Definition file and how to call resolvers of the S1 and S2 from this)

Comment: I am not sure what "dependent" or "independent" means in your case. Please clarify a bit more on that.

Comment: Dependent means - microservices are inter-linked and vice versa